# How to add a quotation before a chapter

Tags: citing, quoting

I would like to add a small quotations as we can find in books before a chapter. 
Is there a simple command to do this ?

I use Xelatex and biblatex, with author-year style

Comment: the KOMA class `scrbook` knows the command `\dictum`

Comment: Package `epigraph`; you probably mean ‘quotation’ rather than ‘citation’.

Comment: Thanks, it works but it gives a citation that is very vertical and too much on the right. Is there another solution, or a way to change this simply ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\begin{document}

\setchapterpreamble[o]{\dictum[Schiller]{Drum prüfe,
wer sich ewig bindet \dots}}
\chapter{Die moderne Ehe}

foo

\end{document}
```

[image]